# How to add custom ops into the graph and make it automatically executed?

Tags: python, tensorflow

While doing some deep learning experiments, I tried to add some extra calculations between convolution layers. However, these calculations must be done via 'sess.run(ops)' and can't be executed automatically, which means I cannot execute the whole graph using sess.run(optimizer) anymore. Now it seems that the only way to solve this problem is to define a complicated ops-execution sequence by myself.

If there are any other ways to add these custom ops into the existing graph ?

```
 import tensorflow as tf

 tensor_A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 6, 6, 1]))
 tensor_W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 2]))
 tensor_B = tf.nn.conv2d(tensor_A, tensor_W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
 tensor_BB = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 6, 6, 2]))
 assign = tf.assign(tensor_BB, tensor_B)
 tensor_C = tf.concat([tensor_B, tensor_BB], 3)

 with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(tensor_C))
```

Comment: Hi Anderson, would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: I have just updated the code =)